# is "Lighting the spark for XYZ" a meaningful phrase in english?

Tags: idioms, american-english, british-english, idiom-requests, german

I am trying to translate or rather come up with an English expression for the German "den Funken überspringen lassen" for a title of an academic paper.  My best solution so far is "Lighting the spark for big data in economics" where I try to convey that "spark" (a programming tool) can be helpful for big data analysis in economics and at the same time have a word game in the title.

Comment: It’s no worse than other marketing-speak. Besides, a slight oddity is sometimes an advantage in a slogan.

Answer (score 1):

Hello SAFEX welcome to EL&U. I looked for examples of "light a spark" online and found a few, although I couldn't find a definition of it as an idiom. Similarly I tried "Set a spark" which seemed more natural to me as a spark is a transitory thing which is used to light something else. This returned a similar number.

I then ran a Google Ngram to find the relative frequency of the two expressions in many books and got [this result](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=set+a+spark%2C+light+a+spark&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cset%20a%20spark%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clight%20a%20spark%3B%2Cc0). The ngram shows that both expressions exist but "light a spark" has, since about 1960, become nore common than "set a spark".

Looking at the German I see that the phrase ends in "lassen" so personally I would read the phrase more as "lay the spark". I added this to the Ngram and found that this is very uncommon so I wouldn't use it. However for me "set the spark" seems to be closer to the German original as it carries connotations of applying a spark to a powder trail or a fuse to trigger an explosion.

As an aside how about using a capital letter for "Spark" or even using the acronym "SPARK" in the title to emphasise the dual meaning of the word in the context of the article?

Answer (score 1):

This answer contains opinion.

A concise solution, I believe, would be ["spark up"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/spark+up) as in "Spark Up Big Data In Economics".

One, this directly prompts (commands) your audience to get active, i.e. to use your tool, which the more impersonal "Lighting/Setting the spark" doesn't do.

And two, this dominant effect contrasts somewhat amusingly against the background of the phrase's other meaning of 'lighting up a smoke' which, importantly, does stay in the background and may even remain unnoticed by some.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't convey what you're trying to say. I'd use *of* rather than *for*: "Lighting the spark **of** Big Data in...".

There's also a transitive form of the verb **"[to spark](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/spark)"** which has the meaning you're looking for:  to cause something to happen or cause something to become animated.

You can also **spark a flame**, which basically means to light it, so "Sparking the flame of Big Data in Economics".

Be a little careful here, though, as "to spark [sth]" is mostly used in a few stock-phrases like "to spark interest in sth." or "to spark the imagination" or "to spark a diplomatic row", and some of those phrases carry a meaning of "cause something bad to happen".

Whatever you do, avoid the more obvious translation [to spark off](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/spark-off). Not because it's British English, but it's mainly used for negative connotations, and often in the stock phrase "spark off another round of [something bad]"